# Word not running certain macros

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

This bit of code has worked for years and now as of today it won't do anything. All I'm trying to do is highlight every instance of a superscript in the document.

```
Sub mcrHighLightSuperSript()
'
' mcrHighLightSuperSript Macro
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find.Font
        .Superscript = True
        .Subscript = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


End Sub
```

Did Word do some update that makes this code invalid?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2201 Build 16.0.14827.20198) 64-bit

Comment: That made me wonder if I was missing a recent update, so I updated whatever was waiting and I still have the problem. I also have rebooted and powered off/on

Comment: I ran the exact same block of code on the exact same document on a different machine, where it worked. The only thing different about the other machine is that it's running Windows 10

Comment: Interesting. I am also using M365 on W11 and I tried a find this afternoon that (incorrectly) used the `.Format` property and couldn’t get it to work. Evidently MS has screwed something up.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt thanks for at least letting me know I'm not crazy

Comment: Do you get any error at runtime? Have you tried using the [On Error statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the long chain of property and method calls, for example:

```
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
```

The [Selection.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.find) method returns a [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find) object that contains the criteria for a find operation. So, you could retrieve the object instance once in the code and then re-use every time you need to set up a property or call a method.